# How can I learn Indian English?

Tags: discussion

I desire learning a distinct Indian English dialect. How can I go about it? When I was learning English, I did not have much exposure to Indian English, but I feel like it has [many features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English#Vocabulary) that are interesting. I would like to try using it in private writings (sometimes shared with others) because I think it would allow me to write and communicate more expressively. It also seems like an interesting group of dialects to learn about.

There are many resources for learning British and American English, but I don't know where you would start for Indian English.

It seems that Indian English normally arises when speakers of Indian languages start learning English, or when English is learned around other Indian English speakers. While I speak standard English, I have no knowledge of any Indian language and do not have the ability to live extensively in India.

I imagine simply consuming a lot of Indian English media, and interacting frequently with Indian English speakers would (eventually) work. However, I am hoping for a more systematic and accelerated method.

Comment: [*Unlike other English varieties, **there is no standard form of Indian English, and it is regarded as a variety of British English.***](https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/english/global-english/indian-english/)

Comment: Why the downvote? I am trying to learn, so if something is wrong, then teach. Do not downvote.

Comment: It's my downvote, because as my comment indicates, you can't "learn Indian English" as a specific variety. That's a bit like saying you want to learn all British dialects as if they were a single unified language. Besides which, I suspect most actual speakers of Indian English would much prefer to be able to speak flawless mainstream English (with retention of a few useful features, such as the ability to use words like ***lakh*** and ***prepone*** unselfconsciously! :)  But it's a request for resources, so the question belongs on ELL Meta

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've down- and close-voted. I cannot help thinking that this remark: _It seems that Indian English normally arises when speakers of Indian languages start learning English_ is so colossally indicative of ignorance (history) that it may indicate that the purpose of the question is to create mischief.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, there *are* at least hundreds of thousands (not hundreds of *millions*) of "native Anglophones" in India whose mother tongue is English. But you can bet your boots practically every single one of them knows not to say things like *I am loving eating this McDonalds burger* except facetiously. And that "misuse" of the continuous verb form (which only arises because it reflects the syntax of Hindi and other native Indian languages) is a stereotypical marker for "Indian English" when that term is a reference to a particular kind of "flawed" English.

Comment: There are some "interesting" aspects to Indian English, though. Some years ago now, I myself asked a couple of question about it here: [***Omission of definite article in Indian English***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/omission-of-definite-article-in-indian-english) and [***I have "a doubt" about whether this phrase is acceptable English.***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/i-have-a-doubt-about-whether-this-phrase-is-acceptable-english)

Comment: It would definitely help if you explained why you wanted to do this and what particular dialect or register you are after. Are you interested in cultivating an accent, or writing it? If someone said they "want to learn US English, but not the standard version in books", I would ask the same question. There are academic texts on Indian English, and dictionaries, and you could start with the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) and follow the references, but I definitely recommend you work out what you actually want to learn and why before you start.

Comment: @StuartF While the phonology is interesting, I think I am more interested in vocab and grammar variations. I edited the question to state this. Although I am surprised by people demanding to know my "reason". A lot of people learn languages out of personal interest and for fun. If you say you want to learn a language or dialect, people do not normally ask "why", but assume you must have some good reason.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Um, what? In the same sentence you accuse me of ignorance, and also declare that you are shutting down my attempts to learn more, by downvoting and trying to close the question (!!!). What sort of insanity is this? Since when is wanting to learn a dialect is a bad thing? Do you also want to fire all the linguists studying BE because they are "creating mischief"? I'm shocked at such a bizarre, anti-learning comment on a site for language learners.

Comment: Watch Indian movies and series **on streaming services**. I doubt you will find a method.

Comment: @Lambie - where I am, you just have to wait for the phone to ring.

Comment: For anyone bemused or confused by Michael Harvey's previous and covert  comment,  Harvey is  referring to  call centres  in the UK that are "manned" by Indian employees who are recognised as Indian English speakers more by their accent than by their competency. It's worth reminding everyone here that there are Indian English speakers on EL&U (not so many on ELL) whose idiomatic English is totally flawless, in grammar and style.

Comment: The OP might find this source to be helpful https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/

Comment: “Even the first point, when I asked him for a video (referral), [he was angry immediately. I was surprised why he  had to get angry first of all; sometimes they do if we doubt their decisions](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/asian-games-2023/india-asian-games/did-not-expect-this-inconsolable-bhavani-devi-alleges-unfair-refereeing-after-losing-asian-games-quarterfinal/articleshow/103968098.cms) (but) it was a quarterfinal.” Interview with Bhavani Devi, Indian fencer

Comment: I think only a native English speaker would be able to identify the speaker's dialect.  In the end, the differences between British, American and Indian English in grammar (accents are a separate issue) are not so great.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you for the link, but isn't this covered by "I imagine simply consuming a lot of Indian English media, and interacting frequently with Indian English speakers would (eventually) work. However, I am hoping for a more systematic and accelerated method."?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I really do not think you necessarily have to be a native speaker of a language to recognize that your interlocutor has an accent or is speaking a dialect. For example, I can identify Spanish from Spain versus South America (and even regions within SA) and I am not a native speaker of Spanish. The same goes, in my case, for French...

Comment: @Lambie I specifically said that accents were a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In all fairness, you did say: only a native English speaker would be able to identify the speaker's dialect.  I don't think one can separate accent and dialect here.

Comment: @Lambie   I also said "…Indian employees who are recognised as Indian English speakers **more by their accent** than by their competency…." I can have a Liverpudlian  accent but speak and write in standard British English. I also said "*In the end, the differences between British, American and Indian English in grammar (…) are not so great*”. Never said there were no differences but I was implying a native speaker would be more likely to identify these differences.  By the way can you tell what accent FumbleFingers or the OP, gomennathan, have?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course not. I have never heard them speak.

Comment: Precisely my point, you may identify FF dialect as being British but no one identify his region if they haven't heard his *accent*.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562095/what-are-the-differences-between-indian-english-and-other-native-varieties) answer.